# How to get a web service object?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm working on implementing some code in C# using a web service, but my only reference is a Java code they used to load test.

Java gets the object calling by calling this

```
lotService=(LotService) ic.lookup("mes-webservices/lotService/remote");
```

where IC is an InitialContext object.

I need to do this same call on C# but I have no idea how. Is there a simple way just like this java method to do it in C#?

Comment: have you looked up how to `consume a web service using C#` on Google

Comment: http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UUzHThdTD1w

Comment: [How to Consume a WebService - Step By Step](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UUzIPxyG3mo) Follow the steps in this link

Comment: I've looked up a lot of this, but nothing has helped me with this particular case, so I opted for asking here to enlighten me a bit. I've never worked with Web Services and maybe my lack of experience with is limiting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do similar thing in C# by adding service reference to web service. I assume your webservice and consuming client are both in .NET.

Psuedo code would be

```
LocationWebService objService = new LocationWebService(); // this is proxy class of web service created when you add web reference
string result = objService.GetLocationName(4); //call web method
```

Comment: I did try this but when I try to call the constructor on it, it won't let me because it's an abstract class. I though this way would just get me a constructed object.

Comment: Why downvotes, is this not the way to reference webservice in c#.

Comment: If it is .asmx service, make sure you have WebService attribute on the service class and WebMethod attribute on the methods you're trying to consume.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps:

1. Add service refrence in your project
2. Create ServiceClient instance
3. By using above created instance call methods it is exposing

That is it.

Answer (score -1):

First right-click your project and select "Add Service Reference."

Once you have it you need to create the service client object. Whatever you named your service reference above you'll have a new type available in your project (named, I think, the service reference name appended with "Client" on the end. Example: if the service is FooService, you'll have a client type called FooServiceClient available.)

To instantiate, you need a binding. You can create it programmatically:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
            {
                CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                AllowCookies = false,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
                MaxBufferSize = 65536,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536,
                MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
                TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
                UseDefaultWebProxy = true
            };
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;

if (isHttps)
    binding.Security = new BasicHttpSecurity() { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport };
```

Then you need an endpoint. Create like so:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
```

Then just instantiate the service client:

```
var serviceClient = new FooServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```

You can call your service methods from the service client instance.

Comment: Why the downvote? This IS a valid way to instantiate a service client. I've done it many times.

Comment: What do you set all these properties of BasicHttpBinding. Which one is different then the default value? Why?

Comment: Those are the defaults. You can change them to customize the binding. I use a helper class to construct my binding by replacing default values with arguments passed in.

Comment: If they are default values, why do you explicitly  assign them. It gives the feeling that you do something special with playing with those parameters. Just use `var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();`

Comment: And assuming that the endpoint hasn't been changed after the `service reference` added to the project, all the code you posted seems to me redundant.

Comment: When you create a new WCF service the binding values are automatically added to the config file. When doing it in code like this it's nice having them all out in front to know what they're set to; just makes it much easier to adjust. It isn't necessary but I just find it easier this way.

Comment: I usually delete the values from the config. Prefer setting it in code.